# How to correctly chain Angular HttpPomise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had an angular Service with a function:

```
    service.getItemByID = function(id) {
        var hp = $http({method: "GET", url: "service/open/item/id",
            headers: {"token": $rootScope.user.token},
            params: {"id": id}});

        return hp;
    };
```

I need to manipulate the returned values before sending them on and I want to keep the HttpPromise structure intact since my controller code is written to expect the success and failure functions of the HttpPromise to be present.

I have rewritten the service to look like this:

```
    service.getItemByID = function(id) {
        var hp = $http({method: "GET", url: "service/open/item/id",
            headers: {"token": $rootScope.user.token},
            params: {"id": id}});

        var newHP = hp.success(
                function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    data.x = "test";  //TODO: add full manipulation
                    alert("success");
                    return hp;
                });

        return newHP;
    };
```

This code works and it work regardless of whether I return hp or newHP.  My question is:
Is this a proper form of HttpPromise chaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.success` returns the same deferred object that it was called on. It does not create a new object. All it does is register a `success` callback on the deferred.

You can use the new reference, or just keep the old reference:

```
service.getItemByID = function(id) {
    var hp = $http({method: "GET", url: "service/open/item/id",
        headers: {"token": $rootScope.user.token},
        params: {"id": id}});

    hp.success(
            function(data, status, headers, config) {
                data.x = "test";  //TODO: add full manipulation
                alert("success");
                return hp;
            });

    return hp;
};
```

---

If you want to, you could just chain them all, and return the deferred object directly:

```
service.getItemByID = function(id) {
    return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "service/open/item/id",
        headers: {"token": $rootScope.user.token},
        params: {"id": id}
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        data.x = "test";
        alert("success");
    });
};
```

Comment: I was also thinking to chain them all. However, that chain doesn't actually return anything. How would he maintain the same success/failure interface with chaining?

Comment: @JohnTseng - `success` returns the original deferred object. You can then make further calls to `success`/`error`/`then` to that returned deferred.

Comment: @JosephSilber - if the consumer of `getItemByID()` will call `success()` again, promise will have to success handlers registered. With no guarantee on which will be called first, so `data.x` might be undefined in a "second" success handler.

Comment: So in this case hp has the same identity as newHP?

Comment: @kamituel - deferred/promise callbacks are called in the order that they were registered, so that the service's callback will always be called before the consumer's.

Comment: @Emmentaler - Yes. They are both a reference to the same object.